# removeClass() when class is clicked in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, class, click

## Important edit:

*The root of this problem was that I using "$" for one part of my function and "jQuery" for other parts. It's not reflected in the provided example code because I didn't transpose my code directly and instead opted to provide a simpler example. Lesson learned: post code as is. Question self-voted for deletion. The answers provided, though useful, essentially demonstrate alternative methods of achieving what's already achievable through the provided code example that I mistook as faulty.*

## Context:

I have a button. When it's clicked I require the removing of the class I'm using to select it in the first place.

The button is styled red when it's "OFF" and styled green when it's "ON".

## Problem:

The class isn't being removed.

## What I've tried:

```
$("body").on("click", ".button_off", function(){
    alert("Selected and new class applied.");
    $(this).removeClass( "button_off" );
    $(this).addClass( "button_on" );
});

//Target the button when clicked when on...
$("body").on("click", ".button_on", function(){
    alert("Unselected and new class removed.");
    $(this).removeClass( "button_on" );
    $(this).addClass( "button_off" );
});
```

*EDIT: Above code edited to include the "." for the ".button_off selector. Previously omitted due to a transpose error.*

## My question:

How do I remove the class when clicking the said class?

Comment: where is your html code

Comment: You missed the dot in `$("body").on("click", "button_off", function(){`.

Comment: @clarus: please mention in your question that you have updated the question after these comments/answers. Otherwise, these comments/answers will look out-of-place for a new visitor!

Comment: @AleksandrM - Corrected but this was just a transposing error. With both handlers correct the problem persists.

Comment: http://codepen.io/BeatAlex/pen/xipaF This works fine for me.

Comment: You have to wait for body to be available (if code put in HEAD section) or delegate to document level instead

Comment: @BeatAlex It works. The root of this problem was that I using "$" for one part of my function and "jQuery" for other parts. It's not reflected in the above example because I didn't transpose my code directly and instead opted to provide a simpler example. Lesson learned: post code as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target both states (classes) as below and change the class depending on the current class.

This example allows you to include further functionality if required. Eg. your alerts.

```
$(".button_on, .button_off").on("click", function(){
    var $me = $(this);
    if ($me.hasClass("button_on")) { 
        alert("Unselected and new class removed.");
        $me.removeClass( "button_on" );
        $me.addClass( "button_off" );
    } else {       
        alert("Selected and new class applied.");
        $me.removeClass( "button_off" );
        $me.addClass( "button_on" );
    }
});
```

Better, if you just need to change the style of the buttons by changing the class you can use:

```
$(".button_on, .button_off").on("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass( "button_on button_off" );
});
```

Comment: This works. I've opted for the first solution because I'll be adding events and conditions other than class toggling. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you miss "." on the first handler?

```
    $("body").on("click", ".button_off", function(){
    alert("Selected and new class applied.");
    $(this).removeClass( "button_off" );
    $(this).addClass( "button_on" );
});

//Target the button when clicked when on...
$("body").on("click", ".button_on", function(){
    alert("Unselected and new class removed.");
    $(this).removeClass( "button_on" );
    $(this).addClass( "button_off" );
});
```

If this does not work, have you tried hadling it like this?

```
 $(".button_off").click(function(){
    alert("Selected and new class applied.");
    $(this).removeClass( "button_off" );
    $(this).addClass( "button_on" );
});

//Target the button when clicked when on...
$(".button_on").click(function(){
    alert("Unselected and new class removed.");
    $(this).removeClass( "button_on" );
    $(this).addClass( "button_off" );
});
```

Comment: Corrected but this was just a transposing error. With both handlers correct the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the "." at the following line :

```
$("body").on("click", ".button_off", function () { ...
```

Comment: Corrected but this was just a transposing error. With both handlers correct the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

instead doing two things you can try with `.toggleClass()`:

```
$("body").on("click", '[class^="button"]', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass( "button_on button_off" );
});
```

[**A working demo in fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ANxDu/1/)

Comment: Apologies but I didn't clarify that I'll be adding events and conditions other than class toggling. In other words, I need handlers to be separate. Jonathon's solution has achieved this for me (the selected answer).

Comment: @ClarusDignus see the upadted answer and the fiddle link, this is the shorter way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

What is the Selector you wont , What Do you mean With **"$('body')"** , you need to make the selector on the button it self so you can do it like this :

```
$(document).ready(funcntion(){

    $('.button-on').click(function(){

         $(this).removeClass( "button_on" );
         $(this).addClass( "button_off" );

    });


});
```

Or You Can Use Css On It From Jquery

```
$(document).ready(funcntion(){

    $('.button-on').click(function(){

         $(this).css('background-color','red!important');

    });


});
```

and Check the Browser Console to see if there is any errors .

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
$("body").on("click", "button_off", function(){
  ...
  ...
}
```

you missed the dot(`.`) before class name.

Try with this code :

```
$("body").on("click", ".button_off", function(){
    alert("Selected and new class applied.");
    $(this).removeClass("button_off");
    $(this).addClass("button_on");
});

//Target the button when clicked when on...
$("body").on("click", ".button_on", function(){
    alert("Unselected and new class removed.");
    $(this).removeClass("button_on");
    $(this).addClass("button_off");
});
```

[Try in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq98H/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".button_off").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("button_on" );
    $(this).removeClass("button_off" );    
});

$(".button_on").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("button_off" );
    $(this).removeClass("button_on" );    
});
```

you can try above code